# What does the word 「っぴい」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, suffixes

Here is the sentence containing the word.

> おことわりだね　おまえみたいな　弱｛よわ｝**っぴい**と組むなんて！
>
> やるんなら　おれひとりでやらあ。

In my opinion, I think it would be transformation of the word 弾き or 'player' but I'm not uncertain if it is correct because the word ends with 「い」. I have searched on some dictionary sites but there is no one describing about it.

Comment: maybe a variation on 弱っぽい?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`～っぴ`/`～っち` is a sort of "suffix" which generates cute-sounding nicknames. Think of it as an rough equivalent of `-ie` as in *doggie*, *walkie-talkie*, etc.

- へたっぴ (下手【へた】 + っぴ, clumsy person)
- [けろけろけろっぴ](http://www.sanrio.co.jp/character/keroppi/) (けろけろ + っぴ)
- [たまごっち](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi) (たまご + っち)

弱っぴい itself is not common (probably I haven't seen this before), but it should simply mean "weak boy/guy".

Comment: So you might well translate it as "weakie", which is a similarly informal word. Contrast "weakling", which has much the same meaning, but is a "proper word".

Comment: @BrianChandler Thanks, "weakie" was something I've come up with, but I didn't know how it "feels".

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes say 弱っちい in stead of 弱々しい. I think 弱っぴい is a transformation of 弱っちい.

Comment: But 弱っちい and 弱々しい are i-adjectives, while the 弱っぴい here appears to be a noun (cos it's 弱っぴいと, not 弱っぴい**の**と)

Comment: Yes、弱っちい and 弱々しい are i-adjectives but I think it is no problem because 弱っぴい is a slang. It may be abbreviated a noun or nominalization. I heard it for the first time.