# What does the word 「おめっち」mean in this sentence?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

It is said by one of supporter in a boxing match between Numata and Aoyama. The supporter said it after Numata had been down.

> しっかりしろい！　**おめっち**からかわれているんだぜ青山によ

I searched and found that おめっち means おまえたち (you guys) so I tried to translate like this:

"Pull yourself together (Numata)! Because of you guys, Aoyama has changed (a way to fight)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this おめっち is **singular** "you" because this person is speaking to one person in front of him. おめ corresponds to お前. <del>っち is probably a suffix explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29635/5010) (oh, it's your question)</del>. おめっち is not common but I sometimes hear おれっち/おらっち, which means "I" rather than "we".

And this からかわれている is not "から + 変われている" but the passive form of [からかう](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8F%B6%E6%8F%84%E3%81%86). から meaning "because of" or "out of" follows a noun that represents an emotion (e.g., 怒りから, 焦りから), but it does not follow a personal noun.

> おめっちからかわれているんだぜ青山によ
>   You're being teased by Aoyama!

**EDIT:** Oh, according to [this explanation](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0%E4%BB%A3%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E#%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1) on Wikipedia and [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BF%BA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1-223141), っち in おれっち is etymologically 達! Still, as far as I know, it never means plural "we" today.