# What does the word 「かまっちって」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, video-games

Here is the sentence which includes the word.

> あたし　エラフィタの近くにいる　**かまっちって**　魔物がときどき落とすよるのとばりが　どーっしても必要なの!

In my understanding, it comes from 構う{かまう}　which mean to concern about. However, I cannot find the reference about 「っちって」.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

かまっち is just the [name of a monster in DQ9](https://wikiwiki.jp/dqdic3rd/%E3%80%90%E3%81%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%80%91) (かま is 鎌, and [-っち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29647/5010) is a kind of suffix). って is a colloquial version of という.

> かまっちって魔物
> monster called Kamatchi