# What does イチ抜けぴ mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, reading-comprehension

[image]

In the first sentence he says he'll be one step ahead in contributing to society.

And then he adds...

"イチ抜けぴ"

From context and given the use of 抜け it seems to be "I'll be leaving the bottom of society first"?

Comment: For ぴ, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29635/5010

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is fine. More literally *I'm the first to leave (the group of 'trash of society')*.

It is almost a fixed phrase to be used by a person who wins some kind of games.

For example, playing [old maid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_maid_(card_game)), the winner leaves the game first, so they say いち抜けた when they win (getting the last matching pair of cards). に抜け, さん抜け etc. are not impossible, but are used less often.

More generally, it can be used when leaving a group of people. I think typically the 'leaver' is wary of the group. In English, it may be close to *I quit* or *I'm out*.

The last ぴ is just a meaningless suffix. It makes it sound more playful.